# Xamarin Forms Picker - Databind a custom data type

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, picker

I'm currently using a xamarin forms picker and the example fworks fine as it's a List.
(https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/xamarin-forms/UserInterface/BindablePicker/)

I need to bind it to a custom type:

```
    StaffList= new ObservableRangeCollection<Staff>();
```

Problem is that the custom type Staff has multiple properties and types. for example:
Id, name, age...

I only want the name to display in picker,

Is this possible, or is there only a list of strings that can attchieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The article you link to gives an example of doing [EXACTLY](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/picker/populating-itemssource/#Populating_a_Picker_with_Data_Using_Data_Binding) what you want.  Use `ItemDisplayBinding` to specify which property of your object you want displayed in the Picker.

```
ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding Name}"
```

Comment: Thanks for that much appreciated

Comment: Or implement ToString on the custom type if you want to combine fields